# automatically start netcat on localhost and remote-host and keep it active

Tags: networking, cron, crontab, netcat, fifo

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2425137/2989893) by @jeremytrimble on Stack Overflow which explains how you can read a FIFO file over network.

I wonder if it’s possible to start these netcat commands automatically, e.g. in a crontab file (@reboot nc …). How would I keep them alive or have them restarted after they are killed?

```
Host1$ mkfifo Host1_named_pipe
Host1$ nc -l 1234 > Host1_named_pipe

Host2$ mkfifo Host2_named_pipe
Host2$ nc Host1 1234 < Host2_named_pipe
```

> Now, when you run a program on Host2 and send its output to
>   Host2_named_pipe, that output will come out of Host1_named_pipe on
>   Host1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server which is always connected use this in a crontab:

```
@reboot nc -k -l 1234 < /tmp/fifo.fifo
```

On the client which is not always on the network or switched on use this command:

```
nc -d $IP_OF_SERVER 1234 > /tmp/fifo.fifo & $SOME_COMMAND
```

The server listens always for a connection on the specified port (thanks to the -k parameter), the client just connects to the server when it needs to.

I’m using this for MPD and its FIFO visualizer. MPD runs on a remote host, but my MPD client runs locally (I’m using ncmpcpp).

*This is the important part of the ncmpcpp config on the local host:*

```
mpd_host = "$IP_OF_SERVER"
visualizer_fifo_path = "/tmp/fifo.fifo"
```

*This is the important part of the mpd config on the remote server:*

```
audio_output {
        […]
        path    "/tmp/fifo.fifo"
        […]
}
```

***Running the 'nc' command on my local machine seems to use a very high amount of resources … ~100% of my CPU performance.***